# php parse cxml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm looking to parse some CXML in PHP...basically all I'm looking to get the value of tags and attributes within it..

how can this be done...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) is what you're after. Go through that documentation and ask more specific questions if you have any particular trouble with it.

Also, [SimpleXML](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp) lets you use XPath expressions, which can come in very handy if you know exactly what you're looking for in the XML document you want to parse.